# Cor of Ex. 1.3.8 of Hartshorne’s Algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Any regular function on $\mathbb{P}^n-(H_i\bigcap H_j)$ is constant, where $H_i$ is defined by $x_i=0$

I know how to do this exercise, but I’m wondering the following statement:

> This gives an alternate proof of (3.4a) in the case $Y=\mathbb{P}^n$, where (3.4a) is: $\mathcal{O}(Y)=k$

Thanks in advance for anyone’s help!

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $Y - (H_i \cap H_j) = U_i \cup U_j$, where $U_i = Y - H_i$ are the standard affine opens. Since $Y = U_0 \cup U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_n$ what we see is that when we try to glue nonconstant regular functions between standard affines, we don't have to do any kind of tricky calculations involving all of them; already on the union of any two of them, the only regular functions are constants, and gluing on more opens can only "shrink" the ring of regular functions (in point of fact it of course does not; the inclusion $\mathcal O(Y - (H_i \cap H_j)) \subseteq \mathcal O(Y)=k$ is an equality hence all intermediate inclusions are as well).

Comment: I’m sorry that I don’t get the meaning of “glue” you mentioned, could you please explain more? Very thanks!

Comment: @BowenL sure. I assume you know the perspective that $Y$ is covered by the standard affines $U_i \cong \mathbb A^n$. Of course, these $U_i$ intersect, and the subsets $U_i \cap U_j \subset U_i$ and $U_i \cap U_j \subset U_j$ are equal, so in particular isomorphic (this could be as weak as homeomorphic; gluing is a topological notion). But we could also view the affines as more fundamental, and think of $Y$ being constructed in the first place as the disjoint union of $n+1$ copies of $\mathbb A^n$ modulo the equivalence relation given by...

Comment: yeah, now I think I almost get your idea, nice of you to reply in detail

Comment: ...a bunch of isomorphisms $\mathbb A^n - \left\{x_i=0\right\} \cong \mathbb A^n - \left\{x_j=0\right\}$ (where we are deleting $x_k$ from the $k$-th copy of $\mathbb A^n$). A more down to earth example is taking the open interval $(0,1)$ and identifying $(0,0.25)$ with $(0.75,1)$ via $x \mapsto x + 0.75$, which yields a circle.